# window.open() ReferenceError

Tags: jquery, firefox, browser, window.open

I have an window open, and if you double click on a div, it will bring up a window with the data that the div contains.  If I close the window, and then double click the same div, it should bring up the window again.

What happens, is that sometimes I will get the error:

```
ReferenceError:IGeared_tavgp_progress Handler is not defined.
```

I do not understand this error, nor do I understand how to get around the problem.

I am using Firefox and Firebug.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
function openWindow(window_title, windowFeatures, window_url)
{
    var     window_obj = null;
    try 
    {
        window_obj = window.open(window_url, window_title, window_features);
    }
    catch( ex ) 
    {
        alert ("Window Open Failed");
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have something to do with the AVG toolbar. See this search: http://www.google.com/search?q=IGeared+tavgp. So, the good news is it's not your code that's screwing things up :)

That said, if you want to save a link to your window object, you should either make it global or return it:

```
var     window_obj = null;
function openWindow(window_title, windowFeatures, window_url)
{
    try 
    {
        window_obj = window.open(window_url, window_title, window_features);
    }
    catch( ex ) 
    {
        alert ("Window Open Failed");
    }
}
```

or

```
function openWindow(window_title, windowFeatures, window_url)
{
    var     window_obj = null;
    try 
    {
        window_obj = window.open(window_url, window_title, window_features);
    }
    catch( ex ) 
    {
        alert ("Window Open Failed");
    }
    return window_obj;
}
```

I guess you probably already knew this, but I felt like including some code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  This pointed me to the issue.  I removed the AVG Toolbar from the browser.

Yes, my code is only vaguely like the one in the post.  It actually does a lot more stuff